# How do you replace all the files in a Github repo with completely new files?

Tags: github

New to GitHub: we're using Appgyver (https://www.appgyver.com/) which generates a new zip file with the project files every time a new build is created.
We're using Github to store our project files and Cloudflare pages uses the files in our repo to host our website.

When creating a new build, the files are very different to the files in our old builds: how would we easily replace all the existing files in our repo with our new files (so the new build is hosted) whenever we want to release a new build?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- `git clone --no-checkout https://github.com/<me>/myProject` your repository: you will get a `myProject/.git` folder, with no actual files checked out.
- generate your files in a separate build folder.

For each build, you would do, from anywhere:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/myProject/.git --work-tree=/path/to/build add .
git --git-dir=/path/to/myProject/.git commit -m "new build"
git --git-dir=/path/to/myProject/.git push
```

That would automatically add/modify/delete any file from the previous HEAD in order to match the new build working tree.

This assumes the build is done locally, and then pushed to GitHub.